# why do iPhoto, Word, and Finder open when I restart Lion?

Tags: macos

I'm using Lion (10.7.2).  I close all applications and restart the Mac.  When it starts up again, it opens windows for iPhoto, Word (to a blank doc), Address Book, and a Finder window.

None of these application are in my "Login Items" for my account.

How do I get Lion to start clean instead of opening all these apps?

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I reinstalled Lion and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 2):

Back up your system before trying this, in case it messes anything up, but I'd recommend this procedure:

In the Finder, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> for "Go to the folder:" then type `~/Library/Saved Application State/`. Delete all the folders in Saved Application State, then press Command-I to Get File Info. In the Get File Info window, check the "locked" box. This should keep applications from restoring their state.